# get height of an element inside flatlist by index in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, view, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to find a workaround for initialScrollIndex in flatlist which is not working properly, I used getItemLayout to fix that, but the problem is that my elements inside the flatlist don't have the same height, they are images with different width and height, i set width for all of them but for the height i need it to be different. I'm looking for a solution to get the height of the View inside the flatlist, I'm using onLayout inside the view but i don't understand how to wire it with the getItemLayout function, this is my code

```
const onScrollToIndexFailed = (info) => {
    console.log(info);
  };

  const getItemLayout = React.useCallback((data, index) => {
    // here i need to get height of every element not fixing it like that
    return { length: 519, offset: 519 * index, index };
  });

<FlatList
        ref={listRef}
        initialScrollIndex={id}
        getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={onScrollToIndexFailed}
        data={posts}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View
            style={styles.element}
            key={item.id}
            onLayout={(event) => {
              const { x, y, width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
              console.log(height);
            }}
          >
            <Post img={item.img} type="all" />
          </View>
        )}
 />
```

Comment: Why don't you try get all images height before FlatList render and pass array with images heights into renderItem func?

Comment: I'm receiving images from a server as url, and i think this solution is not super good in performance since i have 1k photos to render

Answer (score 0):

since the items you are loading are images what you can do is get the size of each image before you display it.
[Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.html#getsize%22) component provides a static method to get the dimensions of an image.
change renderItem to be like this:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => {
          let myHeight;
          Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {   // replace myUri with item 
             myHeight = height;
          })       

          return <View
            style={{...styles.element, height: myHeight}}
            key={item.id}
            onLayout={(event) => {
              const { x, y, width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
              console.log(height);
            }}
          >
            <Post img={item.img} type="all" />
          </View>
        }}
```

Comment: I'm receiving the image from server and it's in another component, please take a look at this repo https://github.com/anisamirouche/ig_example